# Set custom orderfield on checkout succes page

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout

I have create a custom field in the table `sales_flat_order`. When the payment is succesfull i want to add a value to that field, how can i do this?

I've tried to use this `$this->setTicket('test');` in the succes.phtml, but it didn't worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have no exit any function name of `$this->setTicket('test')`; at `Mage_Checkout_Block_Success` class which is do this type of work.

In this case,you need to get Order object and update the data.

Order at success.phtml easily.

```
$orderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
```

then using save function update order files

```
$order ->setTicket('test');
$order->_getResource()->saveAttribute($order , 'ticket'); //for faster save
```